# .when .done function not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little script, that saves to json strings to var with the function getJSON. After that I want to create some divs with the content.

For that I create a each for the cat (categories). In the second each, when the repo fits into a cat it should be display too.
But the script never goes to the .when or .each functions. 
But with console_log() I see the correct response from the getJSON function.

```js
var repo;
var cat;
$.getJSON("api.php?get_repos&release_id=" + $("#release").find(":selected").data('id'), function (
    json) {
    repo = json;
    });
$.getJSON("api.php?get_cat", function (json) {
        cat = json;
});
$.when(repo, cat).done(function(){
    $.each(cat, function (i, j) {
    $(".tab").append('<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCAT(event, \'' + j.cat_name + '\'">' + j.cat_name + '</button>');
    $(".repos").append('<div id="' + j.cat_name + '" class="tabcontent"></div>');
    $.each(repo, function (k, v) {
        if (v.repo_cat == j.cat_id) {
            $("#"+ j.cat_name).append('<div class="repo"></div><p><label><input name="3rdparties[]" type="checkbox" value="' +v.repo_id + '"> ' + v.repo_name +'</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' + v.repo_homepage +'" target="_blank"  class="link"><i class="icon ion-earth"> Homepage</i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' + v.repo_documentation +'"  target="_blank" class="link"><i class="icon ion-university"> Documentation</i></a>');
            $("#"+ j.cat_name).append('<div class="inside">' + v.repo_desc + '');
            $("#"+ j.cat_name).append('<a href="#" onClick="brokenRepo(\'' + v.repo_id +'\');" class="link right"><i class="icon ion-flash-off"> Broken Repo</i></a></div></p></div><br />');
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: I suspect you want:  `var repoajax = $.getJSON...` then `$.when(repoajax, catajax).done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. repo,cat are JSON values, not promise or deferred objects, so `$.when` will not have any effect
2. repo,cat are only set after the `$.getJSON` has completed, so will not be available at the time of the `$.when`

You need to record the jquery promise returned from `$.getJSON` to be used with `$.when`:

```
var repo;
var cat;
var repoPromise = $.getJSON("api.php?get_repos&release_id=" + $("#release").find(":selected").data('id'), function(json) {
  repo = json;
});
var catPromise = $.getJSON("api.php?get_cat", function(json) {
  cat = json;
});
$.when(repoPromise, catPromise).done(function() {
  $.each(cat, function(i, j) {
    ...
    $.each(repo, function(k, v) {
      if (v.repo_cat == j.cat_id) {
        ...
      }
    });
  });
});
```